# Insert, find-min(key) and delete(based on value) functionality in logN with STL containers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory-management, stl, heap

Here's an interesting problem:
Let's say we have a set `A` for which the following are permitted:

> - Insert x
> - Find-min x
> - Delete the n-th inserted element in A

Create a data structure to permit these in logarithmic time.

The most common solution is with a heap. AFAIK, heaps with decrease-key (based on a value - generally the index when an element was added) keep a table with the `Pos[1...N]` meaning the `i`-th added value is now on index `Pos[i]`, so it can find the key to decrease in O(1). Can someone confirm this?

Another question is how we solve the problem with STL containers? i.e. with `sets`, `maps` or `priority queues`. A partial solution i found is to have a priority queue with indexes but ordered by the value to these indexes. I.e. `A[1..N]` are our added elements in order of insertion. `pri-queue` with `1..N` based on comparison of `(A[i],A[j])`. Now we keep a table with the deleted indexes and verify if the min-value index was deleted. Unfortunately, Find-min becomes slightly proportional with no. of deleted values.
Any alternative ideas?

Now I thought how to formulate a more general problem.
Create a data structure similar to multimap with `<key, value>` elements. `Keys are not unique. Values are.` Insert, find one (based on key), find (based on value), delete one (based on key) and delete (based on value) must be permitted O(logN).

Perhaps a bit oddly, this is possible with a manually implemented Binary Search Tree with a modification: for every node operation a hash-table or a map based on value is updated with the new pointer to the node.

Similar to having a strictly ordered `std::set` (if equal key order by value) with a hash-table on value giving the iterator to the element containing that value.

Possible with `std::set` and a (std::map/hash table) as described by [Chong Luo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9209323/1293643).

Comment: What do you mean by `Delete the n-th inserted element in A`. Is it the element that is n-th in the sorted order of elements or is it simply the element that was inserted when there were n-1 elements?

Comment: the element that was inserted when there were n-1 elements.

Comment: The current set of `std::` containers/algorithms doesn't include the "indexed" heap data structure you describe. Such a data structure can be used as an efficient priority queue with dynamic decrease key, delete etc. It's possible to use an "indexed" `std::set` to achieve a similar outcome, although not quite as efficiently - both options are discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209323/easiest-way-of-using-min-priority-queue-with-key-update-in-c/9210074#9210074

Comment: Yes, that's the answer i was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of two containers to solve your problem - A vector in which you add each consecutive element and a set:

- You use the set to execute find_min while
- When you insert an element you execute push_back in the vector and insert in the set
- When you delete the n-th element, you see it's value in the vector and erase it from the set. Here I assume the number of elements does not change after executing delete n-th element.

I think you can not solve the problem with only one container from STL. However there are some data structures that can solve your problem:

[Skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) - can find the minimum in constant time and will perform the other two operations with amortized complexity O(log(n)). It is relatively easy to implement.

[Tiered vector](http://www.cs.brown.edu/cgc/jdsl/papers/tiered-vector.pdf) is easy to implement and will perform find_min in constant time and the other two operations in O(sqrt(n))

And of course the approach you propose - write your own heap that keeps track of where is the n-th element in it.