# c++ priority queue that allows random access updates to the weights?

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I have an algorithm that uses a priority queue to select an element to operate on. However, on each step an O(1) amount of elements in the queue need to have their weights updated.

The standard stl priority queue does not allow for this kind of update. Is there another container in the stl that can be used for this kind of updating?

Comment: Is delete + re-add acceptable?

Comment: Do you mean popping and then adding what you popped?

Comment: You might be able to use [`std::make_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap), but you'd have to remake the heap after your updates which might be too time consuming.

Comment: @Makogan, yes, updating the key value before re-adding.

Comment: That sounds like it is in O(nlogn) since you might need to pop arbitrarily many objects that ahve not been modified. :\

Comment: Use a plain `std::set`. To update the weight, remove the element with the old weight and re-insert with the new.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik how would I find an element in the set by weight? Iteration?

Comment: You would use the same comparator for `set` that you use for your `priority_queue`. Then `set::find` could be used to find an element by weight. Alternatively, use `std::map<Weight, Item>` to make searching by weight more straightforward. `std::multiset` / `std::multimap` if multiple items may have the same weight.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way of using min priority queue with key update in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209323/easiest-way-of-using-min-priority-queue-with-key-update-in-c)